# How do I add multiple in app purchases in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have this in app purchase to unlock level 2 and it works but how do I add another in app purchase to unlock level 3? Do I have to make new functions and add the code for level3? Im not sure how to do this. Thanks!

```
    func unlockLevel() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelTwo")
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
        println("Fetching products...")
    }
    else {
        println("Can't make purchases")
    }
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
    println("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    var count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProducts = response.products
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as! SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == "unlockLevelTwo") {
            println(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            println(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            println(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        }
        else {
            println(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    }
    else {
        println("nothing")
    }
}

func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Error fetching product info")
}

func RestorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()


}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {

    for item in queue.transactions {
        if let transaction = item as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            if transaction.transactionState == .Restored {
                unlockLevel()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if queue.transactions.count == 0 {
        println("not restored")
        displayRestoreAlert()
    }
}

func displayRestoreAlert() {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Level Two has not been purchased on this account.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}



func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
                unlockLevelTwo()
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Restored:
                println("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is quite broad. Conceptually each level is a "product." You need to register multiple products, and then in your game logic check to see which ones have been purchased. This is covered in the programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267 — specifically take a look at the chapters on Retrieving Product Information and Delivering Products. Also take a look at the StoreKit (not SpriteKit) API reference (URL too long).

Comment: I made a second product for it  already I just don't know wether to copy the code again or I could use the same code in the op and put the level 3 code in it.

Comment: The code that I posted was to unlock level two and it works. How do I unlock level 3 using the same code? Im going to use a different product that is called unlockLevelThree. Is that possible?

Comment: Can someone help me? If you don't understand what im saying or need more code let me know. Thanks

Comment: You are looping over `transactions` in your `paymentQueue` function. Each transaction object has a `payment` property which gives you the `SKPayment`. That, in turn, has the `productIdentifier` property, which comes from your `SKProduct`. That's your "unlockLevelWhatever" string. You can use that to decide what store permanently in your Purchased case. Note storing in UserPrefs isn't secure (users can change this without executing a purchase). You are also spelling "Level" as "Leavel" in some places which might result in bugs if you aren't consistent. Does this work for you as an answer?

Comment: This will help you: http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/